# Number of equal permutations of k size of an array

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

Let's say the array is

```
8 9 10 9 4 8 10
```

k = 3

Then the ans = 2.

There are 2 arrays [8 9 10] consisting of index 0,1,2 and [8 9 10] consisting of index 5,3,6 which have same permutation.

Note : all arrays should have elements from distinct index. i.e. no two permutations should have element from same index.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to solve this problem, I would approach like this. You can create a Map with the sorted elements as the keys and there indices as the values. Like so, for the above example,

```
4 - [4]
8 - [0,5]
9 - [1,3]
10 - [2,6]
```

Then you can get the consecutive keys and check if their value list size is similar. This will be a starting point for the complete solution. Hope this helps.